How to catch nginx errors and return status while modifiying response headers
Assets served by nginx sometimes are not found. And they are sent with no Cache-control header set. This causes errors to be cached in users browser. I need to intercept all 4xx error in my nginx, attach response header and return it with correct status.
so my nginx is
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name _;

  large_client_header_buffers 8 16k;

  root   /usr/share/nginx/dist;
  index  index.html;

  location / {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/.*\.(js|css)$ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000, immutable";
    try_files $uri =404;
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 451 = /custom_4xx;
  }

  location = /custom_4xx {
    internal;
    expires off;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0" always;    
    return $status;
  }
}

but this results to 502, due to $status being nothing (appereantly)
question: can I do what I want to do without having to declare a handler for each HTTP 4xx error ?
